# jquery ui fade in color then fade out.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to fade all anchor links colors in and our on mouseenter and mouseleave. This is my best effort so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a').on('mouseenter' , function(){
    $(this).toggle(function (){
        animate({color:"#ee860a"})
            });
        }   
    );
});
```

actually that my best effort was without the toggle function, which might not be appropriate here. Do I need to make 2 functions? 1 with mouseenter and 1 with mouseleave? Or is it best/possible to do with toggle?

Comment: Use the `hover` event, which has two callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. `animate` is used like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a').on('mouseover' , function(){
        $(this).animate({color:"#ee860a"},'slow');
    });
});​
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtBpM/1/

Your approach for the `mouseout` (rather use this than `mouseleave` - same goes for `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`) is ok (just do the same thing with a different event), although you could also use `hover` http://api.jquery.com/hover/ which will allow you to bind the functions for mouseover and mouseout in a single call.

Comment: Yea this is how I had it at first.. Just thought I'd throw in the toggle to show where I was stumped. The tutorials I have been watching have taught me to use ON as it is a more direct approach or some such than using hover. Or that's what I think I remember. Also these are beginner tutorials so hover might come into play a little later.

Comment: The upside for using hover would be that you can bind two events with just one selector call (i.e. faster - although I guess that is a matter of .1 ms) and it is less code to maintain, the downside is that you can get confused when you try to unbind the hover (`$(this).unbind('hover')` does not work) as you'd have to use `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')`. Go with whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('a').hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({color:"#ee860a"});      
   }, function() {
      $(this).animate({color:"#999"});
   });
});
```

Try this :)

Comment: So this also works. I don't know much about hover but it seems to already take into account mouseenter and mouseout (hover.. makes sense).. so the 2 parameters of hover are what happens when hovered and when leaving the hover? I guess I can just go check the api..

Comment: Yes, The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. See [jQuery .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Insert http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js below jQuery and add the follow code to your element:

```
$('#elementToEffect').animate({color: '#ee860a'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a jQuery plugin to animate colors:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

I prefer using a CSS3 solutin:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySwAG/2/

```
a{
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color:#000;
}
a:hover{
    color:#ee860a;
}
```